# Changing a date in a column by 30 based on the date in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, date

I have 1 date column i'd like to change in a database based on the date in another column.  Here are my columns with sample output

```
dtexpires    dtcreated
1/1/13         1/15/13
1/1/13         1/16/13
1/1/13         2/1/13
```

I would like to change "dtexpires" to be "dtcreated" PLUS 30 Days.

Table name is "Customers"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `DATEADD`:

```
UPDATE Customers
SET dtExpires = DATEADD(dd,30,dtCreated)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Comment: Please use `DAY` instead of `dd`. Shorthand can get you into a lot of trouble (compare `y` and `YEAR` for example). If you mean `MONTH`, type `MONTH`.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE customers
SET dtexpires = dateadd(d,30,dtcreated)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your sample data look like you storing string as dates. Assuming `dtcreated is a date type` field

```
update customers
set dtexpires = dateadd(day,30, dtcreated)
```

Comment: I stand corrected. It must have been added in 2005. Never worked in SQL 2000